# How to send large data using jquery post without redirect page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chat, getjson

I'd like to know how to send large data using jquery POST without redirect page?
I have a project to create a mobile chat, and to connect between user app and server, i use JSON.
this is jquery get json script looks like, as we know jsonGet can't deal with large data.

note: bigNumber has 8000 characters.

```
$.getJSON('process.php?input='+bigNumber, function(data) {
    $.each(data.Chats, function(i,output)
    {
        $("#data").append(output.chat);
    });
});
```

*this is what i get when using getJSON for sending big number:* **414 (Request-URI Too Large)**

So, after i send bigNumber, i'll get a response from process.php as json data and adding to the body of html.

//---
now this is my code.

**html file**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#senddata").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "process.php",
            data: { input:$("#bigNumber").val() },
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.Chats, function(i,output)
                {
                    $("#data").append(output.key);
                });
            },
            method: "POST"
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="data"></div>
<input type="text" id="bigNumber"/>
<button id="senddata">Send</button>
```

and this is **process.php**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$key = $_POST["input"];

$simpan_array = array();

$chat = array();
$chat["key"] = $key;

array_push($simpan_array, $chat);

echo json_encode(array("Chats" => $simpan_array));
```

and when i fill the textbox and press the "Send" button, nothing happens.
what's wrong?

---

**Just found out what the problem is, it was an error in json format, which is displayed on process.php**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a POST request instead.  And since `getJSON()` is just a facade for `ajax()`, it is pretty easy to convert:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "process.php",
  data: { input:bigNumber },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.Chats, function(i,output)
    {
        $("#data").append(output.chat);
    });
  },
  method: "post"
});
```

Comment: That usually means that you have an unclosed parenthesis or bracket.  Make sure all your code is closed correctly.

Comment: sir i've tried your code, but nothing happens. would you mind to see my new code on top???

Comment: Of course nothing happens. Where is your click handler. Right now all you do is fire off the AJAX call on page load. But you need to nest the AJAX call inside a click handler.

Comment: and still nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1):

use `$.post`

```
$.post('process.php',{input: bigNumber}, function(data) {
  $.each(data.Chats, function(i,output)
  {
    $("#data").append(output.chat);
  });
},'JSON');
```

Comment: lol i forgot to put "});" in the end of jquery code :D
thanks bipen

Comment: i've tried your code, but nothing happens. would you mind to see my new code on top???

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you try to use websockets for chat application refer this page
[Web Socket Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57060/Web-Socket-Server) or [Introduction to HTML5 WebSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/531698/Introduction-to-HTML5-WebSocket)